# tensorflow - initialize duplicate nets with the same weights

Tags: tensorflow

I want to create two models with the same architecture and exactly the same weights using the tf.layers.dense

```
m1 = tf.layers.dense(input, units=10, activation='relu', name='m1')
m2 = tf.layers.dense(input, units=10, activation='relu', name='m2')
```

How can I set m2 weights and biases to be the same as m1? (same values, not shared weights, so when training m1, m2 weights will not change and vice versa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should firstly create the weights and bias initializers:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

init_kernel = tf.constant_initializer([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
init_bias = tf.constant_initializer([7,8,9])
```

Then you can create the two dense layers and pass the same initializers to `kernel_initializer` and `bias_initializer`.

```
layer1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=inputs, units=3, kernel_initializer=init_kernel, bias_initializer=init_bias)
layer2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=inputs, units=3, kernel_initializer=init_kernel, bias_initializer=init_bias)
```

If I understood your question correctly this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

gorjan answer is correct, but I also found another solution that can be easier to use in more complex scenarios:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    with tf.variable_scope("m1", reuse=True):
        weights_m1 = sess.run(tf.get_variable("kernel"))

    with tf.variable_scope("m2", reuse=True):
        sess.run(tf.get_variable("kernel").assign(weights_m1))
        weights_m2 = sess.run(tf.get_variable("kernel"))       

print(np.array_equal(weights_m1, weights_m2)  # True
```